# Split on a numerical character

Tags: python, split

I have the following text strings:

```
vine-1.3.0.txt
wcwidth-0.1.8.txt
websocket-client-python-0.57.0.txt
xml-security-for-java-2.3.0.txt
```

How can I use split() to remove the -{version}.txt substring and return the following:

```
vine
wcwidth
websocket-client-python
xml-security-for-java
```

I am trying to emulate the following bash/sed command:

```
sed "s/[-0-9.]*$//"
```

Comment: Your `sed` command doesn't recognize/remove the extension, so it does nothing as written.

Comment: From my bash script: `echo "${i%.txt}"|sed "s/[-0-9.]*$//"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsplit()`

```
data = '''vine-1.3.0.txt
wcwidth-0.1.8.txt
websocket-client-python-0.57.0.txt
xml-security-for-java-2.3.0.txt'''

for text in data.splitlines():
    name, *_ = text.rsplit('-', 1)
    print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
vine
wcwidth
websocket-client-python
xml-security-for-java
```

Comment: Note: This will die with an exception if there isn't a hyphen in the string. That might be the correct behavior, but it should be noted in case it's possible you'll be passed pre-trimmed strings (e.g. because two separate parts of the code trim, and sometimes the output of one is fed to the other).

Comment: I will try using glob() to get the file names in a directory, then use rsplit as mentioned above. Keep it simple.

Comment: @deadshot: Cute fix to make it silent on missing hyphen! :-) Leaving the old comment (it describe the behavior of `name, _ = text.rsplit('-', 1)`) for future readers, but I like it either way (as noted, it can be reasonable to treat a missing hyphen as an exception, not a silent success).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are ryt this may not give correct solution for some inputs or raise an exception. But op wants a solution with `split()`, I just provided the answer based on that

Comment: There will always be a hyphen between name and version, so rsplit() should be OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure you only remove a single file extension, plus all digit extensions after the final hyphen, a mix of tools works best:

```
import os.path
import re

# Tweaked regex so it won't treat repeated dots as a match
trimmable_re = re.compile(r'-\d+(?:\.\d+)*$')  # Optional precompile done once at top of file
# or version matching your original sed but matching more than the pattern you describe:
trimmable_re = re.compile(r'[-0-9\.]*$')

name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)  # Split off main extension the nice way
name = trimmable_re.sub('', name)  # Split off numeric extensions
```

---

###### This answer ended up being less simple (forgot how `rpartition` handles missing separator), but kept just for illustration (after making it work, but less simply):

Safest simple solution (that works even if the string doesn't have a hyphen) is `rpartition`:

```
name, sep, name2 = filename.rpartition('-')
name = name or name2  # When hyphen doesn't occur, entire string stored in name2
                      # and name/sep are empty
# Or equivalently, just take first non-empty string from result:
name = next(filter(None, filename.rpartition('-')))
```

where `name` will initially be everything to the left of the final hyphen (empty if no hyphen occurs), `sep` will be `'-'` or the empty string (when there's no hyphen to be found), and `name2` will be whatever came after the final hyphen or the entire string. For the "no hyphen case" we just use `name2`.